# MySQL no abre al intentar ejecutar el Query

Tags: mysql, sql

No se puede ejecutar el query que ya lo tengo archivado; el error de ejecucion se presenta por el constrain de FOREINGKEY

```
create database if not exists santosepulcro character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
use santosepulcro;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario(
    idUsuario INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    nomb1 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    nomb2 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    apell1 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    apell2 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    dni VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    actv INT(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    clave VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    claveTemp VARCHAR(100),
    claveVenc VARCHAR(100),
    idPais INT UNSIGNED,
    idRol INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idUsuario),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Pais FOREIGN KEY (idPais) REFERENCES pais(idPais),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Rol FOREIGN KEY (idRol) REFERENCES rol(idRol)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rol(
    idRol INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    rol VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idRol)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pais(
    idPais INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    pais VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idPais)
);
```

**ERROR QUE SE PRESENTA**

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `santosepulcro`.`usuario` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")    0.328 sec

Comment: La sintaxis para la llave foranea, según la w3c, es diferente, tal vez ese sea el problema. Revisa la [siguiente](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) página. También puedes cambiar de lugar la creación de las tablas a las que hace referencia las foreign key: ponlas antes de la creación de la tabla 'usuario'.

Comment: Asegúrate de crear primero la tabla "país" y la table "rol" antes de "usuario", ya que le podrías estar haciendo referencia a tablas que no han sido creadas.

Comment: Eso hice Blas David O. M. y funciona pero no hay manera que lo haga directo sin ir sentencia por sentencia ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que debes crear primero las tablas `pais` y `rol`, ya que haces referencia a tablas que no han sido creadas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rol(
    idRol INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    rol VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idRol)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pais(
    idPais INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    pais VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idPais)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario(
    idUsuario INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    nomb1 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    nomb2 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    apell1 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    apell2 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    dni VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    actv INT(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    clave VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    claveTemp VARCHAR(100),
    claveVenc VARCHAR(100),
    idPais INT UNSIGNED,
    idRol INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idUsuario),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Pais FOREIGN KEY (idPais) REFERENCES pais(idPais),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Rol FOREIGN KEY (idRol) REFERENCES rol(idRol)
);
```

En cuanto a "ejecutar directamente", tengo entendido que al tenerlos en orden y colocando el `;` al final se ejecutarán, es como el `go` de SQL. Si tienes algún inconveniente coméntalo y lo revisamos. Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Es logico tu comentario